# rails 3 - clear data from heroku app before making live

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a rails app that I've been testing on heroku, it's a simple micro blog style app.

I've a few dozen users registered, they've made a few posts, commented on other users posts and set some personal info about themselves.

I now want to clear out this data before going into beta testing.

How do you recommend I clear out the data? Importantly how can I backup the data and add it back if everything breaks when I remove the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a backup of the Db (via db:pull)

```
heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE_URL
```

will empty your Db.

Comment: Ah, very nice, I didn't know about that one since I never needed to do this before.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do would be:

Heroku uses postgresql (I think), what do you use locally? If you dont use sqlite3, change your setup locally to use it, then do:

```
heroku db:pull
```

heroku will overwrite your sqlite3 database with the schema/data in your heroku environment, you can now back up the db/development.sqlite3 as a copy of your current heroku.

Then:

```
rm -rf db/development.sqlite3
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
heroku db:push
```

You can skip running the migrations locally and do it over in heroku, but there's no point in doing that.

If you ever need to restore your backed database, just do:

```
cp /path/to/my/backup.sqlite3 /path/to/my/railsapp/db/development.sqlite3
cd /path/to/my/railsapp
heroku db:push
```